# PJSIP2.5.5 error while building configure android

Tags: android, android-ndk, pjsip

> TARGET_ABI=armeabi-v7a ./configure-android --use-ndk-cflags
>       configure-android: APP_PLATFORM not specified, using android-24
>       configure-android error: compiler not found, please check environment settings (TARGET_ABI, etc)

I'm getting this error while trying to configure for this target ABI.

How can I resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution.There is a ticket for this problem as NDK13 has
GCC is no longer supported. It will not be removed from the NDK just yet, 
but is no longer receiving backports. 
It cannot be removed until after libc++ has become stable enough to be the default, 
as some parts of gnustl are still incompatible with Clang. 
It will likely be removed after that point.

https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/ticket/1968